# How to solve this infinite radical

Tags: radicals

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{ \dots }}}}}}$$ 
 I don't understand how to solve that. I mean I don't know where to begin.
Tell me if this infinite radical has a solution or converge to a number.
Thanks.

Comment: See e.g. [Nested Radical Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html) and references there.

Comment: Not sure, where exactly this was asked here, but I am pretty sure that it is a duplicate.

Comment: You could also see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774193/is-the-nested-radical-constant-rational-or-irrational) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437209/how-can-i-show-that-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-ldots-exists).

Comment: Is it a constant? Wow

Answer (score 2):

i hope it can help you

> Theorem (Herschfeld, 1935).
>
> The sequence
>   $u_{n}$=$\sqrt{a_1+\sqrt{a_2+.....+\sqrt{a_{n}}}}$
>
> converges if and only if
>
> > $\lim_{n\to∞} sup  a^{2^{-n}}_{n} \lt ∞ $
>
> The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 42, No. 7 (Aug-Sep 1935),
>   419-429.

same question [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437209/how-can-i-show-that-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-ldots-exists?noredirect=1&lq=1)

more information [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435778/finding-the-value-of-sqrt12-sqrt23-sqrt34-sqrt45-sqrt5-dots)